# Disable Constraints in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, storyboard, autolayout

I'm trying to layout a very simple view.  I've placed 4 custom buttons in the view in a grid like spacing.  But when I run the app I get two of the buttons with different sizes.  I've included the storyboard and simulator images here.

I would LOVE to disable constraints but cant find where to do it!  I really don't want them.  This is just for a simple prototype app and in the end I won't even have these buttons, I'll lay everything out in code.

I've tried dragging in 4 individual buttons AND tried just dragging in one and duplicating it to where I want.  I just want them to stay where I put them!  Any help would be appreciated.

-Mark

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Simulator]

Comment: Instead of "laying everything in code" you should better learn what the constraints are, here's the good tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You turn it off in the File Inspector (first tab on left) -- there's a checkbox called "Use Autolayout" (it's checked by default).